# Django URL mapping scenario help required

Tags: django

How can I perform these url mappings in Django:

```
urlpatterns=[
    url(r'^.*', include('Authenticate.urls')),
    url(r'^.*', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="index.html"), name="home")
]
```

With first mapping I want to make sure any url should go through authenticate view first to get authentication done. From first views when authentiaction is done then I want to redirect to the same URL. But this time I don't want it to get mapped with first mapping but I want it to get mapped with second URL so that index.html file can be loaded.

I know, I cant map same url to two times and even if I do so, it will always match with first mapping and because of that the process of authentication will go in a loop.

But when the initial url can be anything and after redirection I want to go on that same URL, I need to map both with url(r'^.*')

How can I overcome this scenario?

Comment: This is not how you should do it in the first place. Read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#limiting-access-to-logged-in-users) to understand how you can make sure users are authenticated and have the correct permissions when accessing a view. So, use view decorators or class decorators.

Comment: But I always want the views to be executed first then the loading of the html.

Comment: So that the views have already done the login_required stuff and then my html is loading

Comment: If I type url www.example.com/someView and this some view is not matching to any view in url files then I should have url(r'^.*', include('Authenticate.urls')), to map it and check it. Later when this default view will redirect to someHtml which I need to map in url file and want to load through index.html file

Comment: This is incredibly bad design. If someone enters a non-existent url because you don't have functionality for it, it's **good practice** to return 404 error page, so there's no reason why you should catch it. But in any case you can't have two different views with the same url. First define all the **known** urls of your app (and the url for your home page should be `r'^$'` indicating the empty path, not just any path), then if you really want to catch all undefined urls to **one** special view that handles it, put it at the end of the urls list.

Comment: And as to authenticating the user, do as I told, decorate your views to check permissions. If you use class-based views and you want **all your views** to use the same permissions, just create one mixin and always add that mixin (parent class) to all your views, that way you don't have to rewrite any code.

Comment: When I had initially written this code only with my django APIs and login decorator, it was working. But when I integrated my APIs with Angular frontend. It started behaving in different way beacuse I am not handling all those endpoints given by frontend.